# Not all Attributes are available for changing programmatically in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, textview

I have a `TextView` object on which I want to change the style to `Bold` and few other  attributes. I am not able to do it. It just doesn't show that option, while I can do it in the `xml` file. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="20dp"
  android:paddingTop="20dp">

  <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table_data"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.037">

    <TableRow
      android:id="@+id/table_row"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameRow"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/moneyRow"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Karma"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

For example, `name.text = key` works, but `name.textStyle` doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView?hl=en#settypeface

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the @CommonsWare's comment, I used Typeface to solve the problem.

```
name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL)  //removes the style.
name.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)  //make it bold.
```